# ¿Cómo filtrar una lista en orden y sin nulos usando Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Tengo unos ejercicios el cual en uno me indica que dando una lista la cual contenga nulos primero debo ordenarla alfabéticamente y quitar los nulos, yo intente con esto ya que se pide *streams* obligatoriamente.

```
Stream<String> lista = Stream.of("p","a","b", null,"c", null,"b", null,"d","j", null,"z","x");

System.out.print("Lista en orden y sin nulos: El primero es ");
lista.sorted()
         .filter(x -> x != null)
         .forEach(x -> System.out.print(x));
```

Según he visto con ese `.filter` me debería quitar los nulos pero al compilar me salta:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El único problema que tiene tu código, es el orden en el que intentas llamar a los métodos del Stream, ya que `sorted()` basicamente *compara* los elementos usando la interfaz `comparable`, concretamente el método `compareTo()` que incluye dicha interfaz (si no me equivoco!)

Con lo cual, cuando intenta hacer `.compareTo(otroObjeto)` en un `null`, revienta. La solución más sencilla es... cambiar el orden en que llamas a `sorted()` y `filter()`!

```
// El problema es que intentas ordenar una lista que contiene nulls, y null no tiene métodos para comparar!
Stream<String> lista = Stream.of("p","a","b", null,"c", null,"b", null,"d","j", null,"z","x");
// Sin embargo, si primero filtramos los objetos nulls funciona correctamente!
lista.filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
/*
 * La única diferencia es que sustituí las lambdas por method references, pero es lo mismo
 * Objects::nonNull es lo mismo que x -> Objects.nonNull(x), que es lo mismo que x != null
 * Lo mismo aplica a System.out::println
 */
```

---

En los comentarios hay un TLDR; para quien no quiera leer tanto.